# Delete a Select Inner Join Query result

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

```
SELECT yturl from ytpointadder a
JOIN watched b on b.watchedyt = a.yturl AND b.ip = a.ip
Group by a.ip;
```

I want to delete the result of the query for exp this query result is :

| yturl | ip | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| eY5WRONGXDI | 197.XX.XX.XXX | 1 |

Though i want to delete it from ytpointadder. I tried :

```
DELETE from ytpointadder a
JOIN watched b on b.watchedyt = a.yturl AND b.ip = a.ip
Group by a.ip;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify same target table  for update (delete) in FROM clause. So you have to use another outer query.

Try:

```
DELETE FROM ytpointadder
WHERE yturl IN  ( SELECT t.yturl FROM (SELECT a.yturl, a.ip from ytpointadder a
                                     JOIN watched b on b.watchedyt = a.yturl AND b.ip = a.ip
                                     Group by a.ip 
                                     ) as t 
                 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a partial query, it should return one column
You may need to use parentheses

try this

```
DELETE FROM ytpointadder
WHERE yturl IN
( 
SELECT a.yturl from  ytpointadder a
JOIN watched b on b.watchedyt = a.yturl AND b.ip = a.ip
Group by a.ip)
```

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't work thought

Comment: What is the error message that appears?